# Get the key from the element just added via $add using AngularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire with Firebase and am wanting to get the key of the element that I just added via the `$add()` method. There's a documented way to do this with "vanilla" Firebase, see "Getting the Unique ID Generated by push()" [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push). It doesn't seem to work with AngularFire's equivalent of `$id`, though.

```
var ref = $firebase(firebaseData.ref()).$asArray();
var newItem = ref.$add({fruit: "apple", color: "red"});
var itemId = newItem.$id;
// Do stuff with itemID...
```

`newItem` is successfully added to Firebase with a new key (such as `-Jf-06c0QX_vMMNL3Aek`), but `itemId` returns undefined.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [AngularFire documentation for $add](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata):

```
var list = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(function(ref) {
  var id = ref.key();
  console.log("added record with id " + id);
  list.$indexFor(id); // returns location in the array
});
```

If you're on an older version of AngularFire, that method might still be called `name` so then you'd need `var id = ref.name();`.

Answer (score 1):

Now `push` returns a `Promise`, so its even easier to get the key:

```
constructor(private afDb: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  my_items$ : FirebaseListObservable<Item[]> = this.afDb.list('my-node');

  this.my_items$.push(this.item).then((item) => { 
    console.log(item.key); 
  });
```